How should a shell script check whether it is running with root privileges?
I'm writing a bash script which I only want the root, or a root, user to be able to run. What is an idiomatic/recommended way for the script to check whether it is running as root / with root privileges?
If it matters, the OS can be assumed to be GNU/Linux.
